# Mapping an array of structs, filtering them out of one var, then extract another var of this struct

Tags: arrays, swift, filter, mapping

I have those 2 structs :

```
struct AResult: Codable {
let section: String
let title: String
let abstract: String
let url: String
let byline: String
let updatedDate: String
let multimedia: [AMultimedia]

enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case section, title, abstract, url, byline
    case updatedDate = "updated_date"
    case multimedia
}

// MARK: - AMultimedia
struct AMultimedia: Codable {
    let url: String
    let format: AFormat
}

enum AFormat: String, Codable {
    case mediumThreeByTwo210 = "mediumThreeByTwo210"
    case normal = "Normal"
    case standardThumbnail = "Standard Thumbnail"
    case superJumbo = "superJumbo"
    case thumbLarge = "thumbLarge"
}}
```

What I need is :

**In multimedia that is an array of AMultimedia, get the element that has the format thumbLarge and then extract the relative url as a String.**

I try something like this:

```
$0.multimedia.filter { $0.format.rawValue.contains("Standard Thumbnail") }.map { $0.url }
```

But xcode tells me that it is a [String] instead of a String.

Hope someone can help me, many thanks !

Comment: The error must relate to the first $0 since your code seems to work fine. You should make use of the enum and replace your filter with `{ $0.format == .standardThumbnail }`

Comment: Or perhaps the error refers to the return value which is a [String] and not a single String

Comment: yes the problem is that I need a Single String. The reason of this is that I am doing all this inside the constructor of a struct that needs a String as parameter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To filter and join the result to one string you can do

```
$0.multimedia
    .filter { $0.format == .standardThumbnail }
    .map {$0.url}
    .joined(separator: ", ")
```